# Разные анимации при одном и том же действии в зависимости от значений

Tags: wpf, c#

Записал несколько анимаций. И нужно,чтоб, например при нажатии кнопки совершалась определённая анимация.
Это сделал.

А как сделать, что б в зависимости от определённых значений, проигрывалась та или иная анимация, тоесть, если например значение метки "такоето", то проигрываем эту анимацию, а если "такое-то", то ещё какуюнибудь и тд. ?
Это с конвертором делается? или как? если ктото знает, напишите пожалуйста код.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь не вижу необходимости в каких-либо конвертерах. Необходимо определить ваше событие, когда меняется ваша метка. Затем в процедуре обработки этого события напишите логику, которая будет реализовывать ваш замысел, например:

`void metka_changed(object sender, Event__ e)
{
string s = metka.Text;
switch (s)
   {
case "metka1": 
  {animation1(); break;}
case "metka2": 
  {animation2(); break;}
   }
}`

Анимацию как таковую можно реализовать в коде (см справку по анимации) или же создать набор анимации в ресурсах приложения, а затем загружать ее из ресурсов и прикреплять к нужным свойствам. Если же искать реализацию в XAML, то она может быть настолько запутанной и огромной, что боюсь вы не справитесь. Хотя, если вас не пугают многочисленные и глубокие теги, можно все же реализовать через XAML, но это, я думаю, не имеет смысла (просто убъете время и не получите ни гибкости, ни красоты).